# Prove Matrix Power for $2 \times 2$ matrix using mathematical induction

Tags: linear-algebra, discrete-mathematics

Using mathematical induction, prove that for any diagonal $2 \times 2$ matrix $A = \begin{bmatrix} a & 0 \\ 0 & b \end{bmatrix}$, that

$$A^n = \begin{bmatrix} a^n & 0 \\ 0 & b^n \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: If $A$ can be *any* $2 \times 2$ matrix then this is false.  Just let $A = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$ and see what happens with $A^n$!

Comment: Or do you mean $A$ is diagonal, $A = \begin{bmatrix} a & 0 \\ 0 & b \end{bmatrix}$?

Comment: Yeah it is diagonal,  i didnt know how to show it in the edit.

Comment: Just say, "$A$ is diagonal."  Also, check out $LaTex$, makes your math look great!  And its easy to get started; right click on any $LaTex$ equation and then choose "show as $TeX$" and you'll see how to do what others have done!

Comment: Meanwhile, check out the product of $A$ and $A^k$, assuming $A^k = \begin{bmatrix} a^k & 0 \\ 0 & b^k \end{bmatrix}$!  And thanks for the clarifying edit!

Comment: [How to format mathematics on this web site](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: thank you very much for LaTex, i was just about to edit it properly and someone else already did it

Comment: Well, you're off to a good start!  Any new ideas on your problem?

Comment: well i looked at the product of A and A^k. I just dont know how to prove it by math induction

Comment: OK, I answered your question!  Hope this helps.  Feel free to ask if you need more info!  Regards, RKL

Answer (score 1):

$A$ is diagonal, that's a given, so we can write

$A^1 = A = \begin{bmatrix} a & 0 \\ 0 & b \end{bmatrix} \tag{1}$

for some scalars $a, b$.  (1) is the base case, or "starting point", of our induction; it is the $n = 1$ case of what we are trying to prove.  Now suppose that

$A^k = \begin{bmatrix} a^k & 0 \\ 0 & b^k \end{bmatrix} \tag{2}$

holds for *some* positive integer $k$.  Then

$A^{k + 1} = AA^k = \begin{bmatrix} a & 0 \\ 0 & b \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} a^k & 0 \\ 0 & b^k \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} a^{k + 1} & 0 \\ 0 & b^{k + 1} \end{bmatrix} \tag{3}$

by the ordinary rules of matrix multiplication.  We have seen that the desired conclusion holds for $n = 1$, and that if it holds for any integer, it holds for the succeeding integer; so the case $n = 1$ implies the case $n = 2$ implies the case $n = 3$ *und so weiter*; this is the essence of an inductive proof, and it is now complete for this problem!  ***QED.***

***P.S.***  *und so weiter* is German for "and so on"; I think I read once that David Hilbert liked to use the phrase; I guess I hope a little Hilbert rubs off on me!  Monkey see, monkey do!  But D.H. was a King Kong mathematician if there ever was one!

Hope this helps!  Cheerio,

and as always,

***Fiat Lux!!!***